# Python 2.7 Correct syntax to re.match accented characters in a Unicode string?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode

I have a function with a single parameter that is a unicode string, which contains accented characters. I want to find one or more occurrences of a pattern within that string and print it out.

I don't know how to correctly format the pattern, or correctly use re.match with unicode, or extract the match.groups() with unicode. It's so much easier with ASCII. Argh.

Python 2.7

```
sentence = "These characters, ÄÜ, are special."

def findInSentence(sentence):

    pattern = re.compile("ÄÜ", re.UNICODE)
    return re.match(sentence, pattern).groups()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues to use Unicode properly:

1. Declare the encoding of the source file.
2. Save the file in the declared encoding.
3. Use Unicode strings.

In addition, Use `re.search` correctly as @M42 pointed out.

There are also no `groups()` in your search pattern, so use `.group(0)` to print out the match if it exists.

Note that `re.UNICODE` is not required in this instance because it only affects how the special match sequences `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S` work and they aren't being used.

```
# coding: utf-8
import re

sentence = u"These characters, ÄÜ, are special."

def findInSentence(sentence):
    pattern = re.compile(u"ÄÜ", re.UNICODE)
    return re.search(pattern, sentence).group(0)

print findInSentence(sentence)
```

Output:

```
ÄÜ
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

`re.match` is anchored at the beginning of the string and `re.search` searches the entire string.

The syntax for `search` and `match` are:

```
re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

You've inverted the pattern and the string.

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't encode the string or use the re. functions without getting errors.

Comment: @user1473511: exchange pattern and string, see my edit.

Comment: sentence = "These characters, ÄÜ, are special."
This line throws an error.

Comment: Thank you. That was A problem, but there is something else going on preventing the console from working. Thank you again.